# Error inflating class com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton

Tags: android, floating-action-button, material-components, material-components-android

Although there is a similar question, it does not give me a solution. When I'm trying to use `com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton` it runs well. But if I try to use `com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton`, it gives errors.

My code in the XML file:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/book_profile_write_review"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/author_name"
    android:text="@string/book_name"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />
```

logcat:

```
2019-11-14 12:30:21.997 21326-21326/com.bookaholic.shahad.bookaholicbd E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.bookaholic.shahad.bookaholicbd, PID: 21326
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bookaholic.shahad.bookaholicbd/com.bookaholic.shahad.bookaholicbd.activities.BookProfile}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2974)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3059)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1724)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
    at com.bookaholic.shahad.bookaholicbd.activities.BookProfile.onCreate(BookProfile.java:20)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7258)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7249)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1222)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3059)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1724)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
    at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:243)
    at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkMaterialTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:217)
    at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:145)
    at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:76)
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.<init>(MaterialButton.java:200)
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: Check your compiled  SDK version? maybe it won't be supported for this

Comment: Your app theme has to inherit from a **Material Components theme**. You can find all the info in the [official guide](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#4-change-your-app-theme-to-inherit-from-a-material-components-theme).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

From your logcat

> `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).`

So add a material theme for your app/current activity will fix this issue

1) add dependency*    (latest / more stable version)

`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha01'`

2) Create a new theme

```
<style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Add attributes here -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceButton">@style/AppTextAppearance.Button</item>
</style>
 <!--To fix rendering in preview -->
 <style name="AppTextAppearance.Button" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
</style>
```

change parent material theme according to you **parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.***

3) change app theme or current activity theme in manifest

```
android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme"
```

or

`<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
  android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme"> </activity>`

4) If you found any rendering issue in previews, adding themes to ExtendedFloatingActionButton will fix this

```
Failed to find '@attr/textAppearanceButton' in current theme.
```

add theme to ExtendedFloatingActionButton  **android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme"**

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme"
        android:text="ExtendedFab"            
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_add_a_photo_white_24dp"
       />
```

For more info visit [Material Design Page](https://material.io/develop/android/components/extended-floating-action-button/)

Comment: Better the  `1.1.0-beta02 `. Also there is no reason to define  `textAppearanceButton `. Also the  `Widget.MaterialComponents.ExtendedFloatingActionButton.Icon ` is the default style for the  `ExtendedFloatingActionButton ` then it is useless to apply it in the layout.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a an app or activity `theme` that is a descendant from `Theme.MaterialComponents`.

You can see in the trace: 
`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).`

Comment: I changed theme from Theme.AppCompat to Theme.MaterialComponents and this solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

### AndroidManifest.xml

> Update your app theme to inherit from one of these themes, e.g.:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
    <!-- ... -->
</style>
```

### build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha03"
}
```

GL

[Source](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md)

Answer (score 0):

Here this one work for me

```
 <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme" .................. /> 



<style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Add attributes here -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceButton">@style/AppTextAppearance.Button</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same error after updating to targetSdkVersion = 32.
My activity already had a theme inheriting from MaterialComponents.
The issue was that I was setting

android:background="?selectableItemBackground"

to the ExtendedFloatingActionButton. So if you're trying to override the background, it will give you error. Remove that and it should work.

Answer (score -1):

If you plan to make an Application using material Design Components, consider using `Theme.MaterialComponents.*` because in some occasions you will face some inflating errors regarding XML

More information about Material Design Components can be found here: [MATERIAL.IO](https://material.io/develop/android/components)